# Is there a term for a question that is not rhetorical?

Tags: terminology

[Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rhetorical) defines a "rhetorical question" as one "asked in order to produce an effect or to make a statement rather than to elicit information".

Is there not a term for a 'normal' question, one asked to elicit information?

Comment: http://glottopedia.org/index.php/Question

Comment: an interrogative sentence? (this has the explicit meaning of "interrogating" for an answer)

Comment: "Non-rhetorical"?

Answer (score 2):

The term **information-seeking question** is often used by linguists in precisely this sense, contrasting them with rhetorical questions - for instance, in [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0023830918816351) by linguists at the University of Konstanz.

(Full disclosure: these are colleagues of mine in a large [research group on questions](https://typo.uni-konstanz.de/questionsInterfaces/).)